# Purpose of :A when creating virus (Ethical Hacking please)

Tags: malware, virus

I am studying how to make simple virus (for Ethical Hacking in Virtual Computer)

This video gives demonstration, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkxtOr2RLbY

In short, you create .bat file with following

```
@echo off
:A
start
goto :A
```

I cannot understand what

```
:A
```

is for.

I thought A: was floppy drive, which is no longer in use. But what is `:A`?

Kindly explain

Comment: This is not a security question, but a batch file language question. Migrating to SuperUser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off     -Turns off outputs within the CMD windows
:A            -Creates a new label we can go to later
start         -Opens a new command prompt window
goto :A       -Goes back to our label above
```

It would infinitely run the same `start` command, creating infinite CMD windows.

If, however, it had been `A:`, then the second line would attempt to go to the A: (A floppy drive perhaps), and the goto would just fail.

Answer (score 1):

It's a label for the goto statement. Essentially you're marking that line as A and then the goto statement says "Go back to the line marked as A". Thus this creates an infinite loop.

Here's some more information: http://ss64.com/nt/goto.html